# How to embed spring declarative JPA transaction inside a legacy non managed and jdbc based code

Tags: spring, spring-transactions, spring-orm

We have a legacy web application using plain JDBC connection and not being spring managed.
We are currently moving to a full spring/JPA managed application.

Currently legacy application is calling spring beans.
Spring beans are correctly marked with `@Transactional`.
The legacy application runs behind an `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter`.

### Use case

1. Legacy App opens JDBC connection
2. Legacy App applies an update with JDBC connection without committing
3. Legacy App calls a spring bean method annotated `@Transactional`
4. On method end, Spring commits
5. **Legacy app cannot rollback the first update**

How can I start a Transaction in the legacy app, that will be joined by `@Transactional` in order to avoid unwanted commit?

Comment: Wrap the datasource used in the legacy app in a `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy`. This allows legacy JDBC code to participate in a Spring based environment.

Comment: I tried with the proxy. It is not enough.

When the connection is closed from the legacy app, Spring is not aware of it and throws an exception when trying to make the final commit

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to commit against JDBC connection
 at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:116)
 at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:180)
 ... 48 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is null.

Comment: Then you aren't using the `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy` correctly... Post some code and configuration.