# How to share database connection between legacy web application and spring

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-transactions

I have a legacy web application and plan to migrate it slowly to spring. One of the first steps is to migrate a small part of the applications persistence layer to spring data with JPA, while also not breaking any existing database accesses. The issue is, that the legacy application starts a transaction which should be used/continued by spring.

Example:

- Legacy app retrieves a connection from the custom connection pool
- Legacy app applies an update with this connection without committing
- Legacy app calls a spring service (+ JPA Repository) method annotated with @Transactional

The last step is perfomed on a different connection/transaction and spring commits the connection. Now in case of an error, the legacy app cannot rollback the part that was committed by spring.

The goal is, to be able to share existing connections with spring, so that in the example above, everything (legacy service and spring service) use the same connection and therefore everything is either committed or rolled back atomicly.

I have tried to:

- use `TransactionTemplate` with a custom `AbstractPlatformTransactionManager` or `DataSourceTransactionManager` which allows to set a connection/DataSource just before using the transaction template. For some reason spring still creates a new transaction or throws an exception with "No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread"
- Use the `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy` to make connection available to spring. This probably does not work without completely replacing the existing connection pool.

Is there a good way to make this work without replacing the connection pool (which likely would break several parts of the application)?

This is a bit related to: [How to embed spring declarative JPA transaction inside a legacy non managed and jdbc based code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329518/how-to-embed-spring-declarative-jpa-transaction-inside-a-legacy-non-managed-and)
However, my application has a custom Database Pool which does not use a `DataSource`, so I can't really figure out how to use the `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy` (if thats even possible).

More context:

This is how the connection/transaction handling currently works:

1. A client makes a request to the server
2. A filter injects a context which holds a connection. This connection comes from the legacy connection pool which actually uses a
   JPA EntityManager to get the connection. The transaction also starts here.
3. The method that the client wants to call is executed and the context with the connection is passed on to every other service which is used.
4. If at any point an error occurs, the transaction gets rolled back, otherwise the transaction gets committed and returns to the pool.

Now at step 3, one of these "other services" might as well be a spring service with a Spring Data Repository. This repository has to use the same connection and transaction and should never commit. The commit/rollback handling should still be responsibility of the legacy service.